# Getting Authorization error when trying to retrieve all members of an AD Group using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph to retrieve all members of a Group. But I am getting the below authorization error message. I am not being able to figure it out as i started to learn it from today. I also went through some blogs regarding this but couldn't find out the root cause.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
> Exception Details: Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
> Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
> Inner error:
> AdditionalData:
> date: 2021-09-24T11:25:11
> request-id: ef3e82a6-f1df-4018-bccb-2eea075a934f
> client-request-id: ef3e82a6-f1df-4018-bccb-2eea075a934f
> ClientRequestId: ef3e82a6-f1df-4018-bccb-2eea075a934f

**Following is my code:**

```
private static string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
private static string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
private static List<string> graphScopes =
      new List<string>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppScopes"].Split(' '));

public static async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> GetEventsAsync()
{
      var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();

      var members = await graphClient.Groups["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"].Members.Request().GetAsync();
}

private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
{
      return new GraphServiceClient(
          new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
              async (requestMessage) =>
              {
                  var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                      .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                      .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                      .Build();

                  var tokenStore = new SessionTokenStore(idClient.UserTokenCache,
                          HttpContext.Current, ClaimsPrincipal.Current);

                  var accounts = await idClient.GetAccountsAsync();

          
                  var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenSilent(graphScopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                            .ExecuteAsync();

                  requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                      new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
              }));
}
```

**AppSettings:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ida:AppID" value=[App Id] />
    <add key="ida:AppSecret" value=[App Secret] />
    <add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44359/" />
    <add key="ida:AppScopes" value="User.Read.All Calendars.Read" />
</appSettings>
```

I am assuming that I may need to adjust the AppScopes values in the appSettings but not sure. Can anyone provide me some hits to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of group's members you need the following permissions

[image]

In your app settings you specified different set of permissions: `User.Read.All` `Calendars.Read`

Check permissions for your application in Azure Portal

[image]

Resource:

[List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)